# add new properties to java pojo in nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

in nashorn, i try to accomplish something like this

```
a.test = function(key){print(key);};
```

but variable a is java entity(pojo), when i do

```
a.test( "someting" );
```

it give me error

> amavisca.monsterpuzzle.entity.a@adfbc1 has no such function "test"

my question :

how to add java pojo, new properties in nashorn?

example :

```
 a.test = function(key){print(key);};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. POJOs in Nashorn act as if they were sealed JS objects (they are non-extensible and their properties are non-configurable, same as if they had `Object.seal(obj)` called on them).